# mydatabase is not created in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

hi i am writing my database in kotlin and want that room data base to be used in java class .But on running it ,it is showing error that myAppdatabase is not implemented.

this is my Database cls

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Feedback::class),version = 1,exportSchema = true)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun dao(): Dao

    companion object {

        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

         fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabase? {


            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(MyDatabase::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            MyDatabase::class.java, "feed.db").allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE

        }
    }

}
```

this is my java class

```
context=this.getActivity();
INSTANCE=MyDatabase.Companion.getInstance(context);
myDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),MyDatabase.class, "feed.dp").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
```

Comment: If you've already called `MyDatabase.Companion.getInstance(context)` and assigned it to the `INSTANCE` variable, then that's your database instance right there. Why are you also trying to build another Room database?

Comment: in my instance in java class it is getting null